# C# data structure - what is the best way to reference a calling object's property?

Tags: c#

My data is currently structured as follows:

```
class A
{
    B[] bArray;
    C[] cArray;

    A()
    {
        fillB();
        fillC();
    }
}
class C
{
    X[] x;

    insertX() // adds an X element to the x array
    {
        X newX = new X();
        newX.b = findB(searchParam); // returns the matching element from bArray
        // the rest of the code adds newX to array x
    }
}
class X
{
    B b {get;set;} // reference to an element bArray
}
```

This is how the data is currently structured. The problem I'm having is I'm not sure

1. If I'm structuring this properly
2. Where to place the findB function. The findB function was originally in class A, but class A is the calling object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to asking questions about code, so bear with me please.

Comment: If the object is to provide data from `B` then the class that owns `B` should probably provide the method, though it's purely up to how you plan to use the classes you create that dictate where it goes. It doesn't _have_ to be that way, but that's one way to think about it.

Comment: This is a classic case of [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You'd benefit more by explaining what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects that are being composed/aggregated usually *do not* know about their parents. So no, I wouldn't say your structure is very good.

That is, in your example, `C` has **no idea** that it is being created by `A` and so doesn't know anything about `bArray`. Depending on the context, this is *exactly how it should be*.

Now, you could *pass* an `A` reference to `C`:

```
class C
{
    A parent;
    X[] x;

    public C(A parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    insertX() // adds an X element to the x array
    {
        X newX = new X();
        newX.b = parent.findB(searchParam); // returns the matching element from bArray
        // the rest of the code adds newX to array x
    }
}
```

And put `findB` in `A` again. Thats where it should go, since its the **only** thing that knows about `bArray`.

But that tighlty couples `C` to `A`. That might be ok in your situation, it might not. In general though, tight coupling like that is to be avoided. Without better class names/context, its impossible to say what a better design would be in your situation.

Comment: In this case, they will always be tightly coupled. C will always have A as a parent. This will work out great! In the future, I'll try to give better examples. EDIT Why is it bad practice to do this btw? Seems like it making a parent object property could be useful.

Comment: @a-a-ron Like I said, tight coupling. Sometimes a `parent` makes sense, but *many* times it doesn't. You just have to know what you are doing.